# Constraints not being enforced (consistently) while using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql, sqlbulkcopy

On our database table we use two unique non-clustered indexes to create a unique constraint across four fields. We use two due to the fact one of the fields, `ZipCode` is a nullable field. If a record exists on the table with a `null` entry for `ZipCode`, we don't want a scenario where a new record matches the three other fields but has a defined `ZipCode` and gets added (and vice versa).

The problem is it seems using a `SqlBulkCopy` neither constraint is being enforced as you can add any record you like regardless of what you already have on the table.

In another program we have we use the `Entity Framework`, since we are loading a significantly smaller amount of data. Using the EF, these constraints work perfectly (they are currently in production). However, using the `SqlBulkCopy` it appears they are being completely ignored.

**T-SQL**

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ_ChannelStateEndDateZipCodeNOTNULL] ON [dbo].[ZipCodeTerritory]
(
    [ChannelCode] ASC,
    [StateCode] ASC,
    [ZipCode] ASC,
    [EndDate] ASC
)
WHERE ([ZipCode] IS NOT NULL)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ_ChannelStateEndDateZipCodeISNULL] ON [dbo].[ZipCodeTerritory]
(
    [ChannelCode] ASC,
    [StateCode] ASC,
    [ZipCode] ASC,
    [EndDate] ASC
)
WHERE ([ZipCode] IS NULL)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**C#**

```
Dictionary<DataRow, string> faultyRows = new Dictionary<DataRow, string>();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    //Open Database connection
    connection.Open();

    //Create transaction objects
    SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints, transaction);
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ZipCodeTerritory";

    //Load data and initialize datatable
    DataTable dataTable = LoadData(inserts);
    IDataReader reader = dataTable.CreateDataReader();
    DataTable dataSchema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
    DataTable tmpDataTable = InitializeStructure();

    //Create array to hold data being transfered into tmpDataTable
    object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //Clear temp table for single-record use
        tmpDataTable.Rows.Clear();

        //Get data for current row
        reader.GetValues(values);

        //Load values into the temp table
        tmpDataTable.LoadDataRow(values, true);

        //Load one record at a time
        try
        {
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(tmpDataTable);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            faultyRows.Add(tmpDataTable.Rows[0], ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've found that this constraint actually is being enforced if the `ZipCode` field is defined. Any match of the `ChannelCode`, `StateCode`, `ZipCode`, `EndDate` fields will result in a `SqlException` with the following `Message` property (pulled from the specific text I just ran):

`Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ZipCodeTerritory' with unique index 'UQ_ChannelStateEndDateZipCodeNOTNULL'. The duplicate key value is (9, WA , 98102    , 9999-12-31)`

However, this is the only time I can get one of our two constraints to fire.

Comment: is it feasible to switch to `bcp` command? If you can use that you can put `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` option on it otherwise it will ignore constrains just like `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: SqlBulkCopy has crazy(!) defaults. See the duplicate. It will disable existing foreign keys for example. This is a DDL action, performed implicitly without warning.

Comment: @SaUce: How is the a duplicate?? I have `SqlBulkCopyOptions` set in the constructor, same as the answer for that question. We also have no triggers on the table.

Comment: @SaUce I'm also not sure what you mean by "switch to `bcp` command"

Comment: I removed duplicated flag, at first I did not notice the `SqlBulkCopyOptions` had to scroll over to the right. By switching I mean write SP that will execute BCP command and all you need to do is pass the required attributes.

Comment: By SP I'm assuming you mean a stored procedure. No, I want to use the method above due to error handling concerns and the ability to display to the user the specific message that gets kicked back when a constraint is violated.

Comment: One of the features of SqlBulkCopy is to purposely ignore constraints which is part of why it's so fast

Answer (score 0):

This was occurring due to the method I used transfereing data from a Model object (I am still using the Entity Framework in places) to a `DataRow`. Below is the method I am using now. Prior to my fix, the `ZipCode` field, when `null`, was instead being placed into the `DataRow` column as an empty string. Since this wasn't technically a null field, the constraint was not triggered.

```
    private static DataTable LoadData(List<ZipCodeTerritory>zipCodeList, bool update = false)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = InitializeStructure();

        foreach (var zipcode in zipCodeList)
        {
            DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();

            try
            {
                row[0] = zipcode.ChannelCode.Trim();
                row[1] = zipcode.DrmTerrDesc.Trim();
                row[2] = zipcode.IndDistrnId.Trim();
                row[3] = zipcode.StateCode.Trim();
                row[4] = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(zipcode.ZipCode) ? null : zipcode.ZipCode.Trim());
                row[5] = zipcode.EndDate.Date;
                row[6] = zipcode.EffectiveDate.Date;
                row[7] = zipcode.LastUpdateId;
                row[8] = DateTime.Now.Date;
                row[10] = zipcode.ErrorCodes;
                row[11] = zipcode.Status;

                //Add the Id column if we're doing an update
                if(update) row[9] = zipcode.Id;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```